Stack overflow - save your work and restart RAD Studio 12
I get this error very often when I open some of my projects.

Then I simply close the IDE and open it again and then it's all good. I'm on Delphi 12.1 and I never had this issue on Delphi 12.0
I also don't know if this is related yet or not, but I don't think I've ever seen this on any of my small projects. It just happens on my larger projects. It also doesn't happen every time, just sometimes.
I don't have a lot of third party components installed either. Just some random things from GetIt. But I had the same components on Delphi 12.0 and Delphi 11.3 also.
List of installed components:

All of the TMS Components from GetIt
OmniThreadLibrary
JEDI
FMXLinux

What is this "Danger" error and what's causing it?

Something that has happened to me several times the last week is that I cannot see images in posts. Has anyone else observed this issue? In this case, I only see the alt text as a link, and following this link I am met with "oh no, that request didn't look right
RayID: 87a51f805ace09b0"

@AndreasRejbrand Have you seen this https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395024/ I see images normally. I think I saw some question on main Meta from someone with similar problems as yours, but I cannot quickly find it now.

@AndreasRejbrand Image shows on my end

There are some reports about IDE running into stack overflow errors for 12.1. But there may be different causes. I would suggest filing a bug report at https://embt.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portals with more information, especially which specific components and plugins you have loaded (you can also add them in this question as there is possibility that some of those are the cause)

Regarding the "danger" (which I also recall having seen in message boxes like this one, even though I cannot see the screenshot you attached in this Q): When an access violation (not close to addr zero) or stack overflow error occurs in a program, something is very, very wrong with the process. This is typically (arguably always) due to a bug in the program's source code. Hence, you cannot trust the program to work correctly after such an event. It may well be the case that some memory has become corrupted, and then, in theory, anything could happen. In practice, this is rarely very ...

... spectacular, but since the IDE may well malfunction from that point on, a restart is a good idea.

Submit a bug report to the vendor of this software

Have you already installed Patch 1 for Delphi 12.1?

There is nothing that anyone here can do to help with this issue. It's internal to the IDE, or related to one of the third-party packages you've indicated that you're using (but have not named). File a bug report with EMBT. They have the IDE source and can troubleshoot the issue - we can't.
